# Использование fopen_s в внешней функции

Tags: c++, функции, visual-studio-2015, fopen, передача-параметров

Чего-то накосячил в следующей функции:

```
// Открытие файла
int FSB_OpenFile(FILE* FDB, const char* adr, const char* mode) {
    if (!std::filesystem::exists(adr)) return -15;
    if (fopen_s(&FDB, adr, mode) != 0) return -8;
    return 0;
}
```

Вызов:

```
FILE* FDB = NULL;
int errorcode;
std::string FullAdr = "Полный адресс до файла";
errorcode = FSB_OpenFile(FDB, FullAdr.c_str(), "r");
```

Как итог - внутри функции *FDB* присваивается файл, а вне ее - по прежнему *NULL*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FSB_OpenFile(FILE** FDB ...

...

FSB_OpenFile(&FDB, ...
```

Ну, или передавайте по ссылке...